# Mysql subquery select column properly

Tags: mysql

I have sql code below which results

```
SELECT user_id, proj_id, done
FROM  `project` 
WHERE theme = 1
AND user_id = 123
AND done =1
```

// result

```
user_id     proj_id  done
123          17       1
123          18       1
123          20       1
```

how can I SELECT in a way like this?

```
user_id | proj_id_17 | proj_id_18 | proj_id_19
123           1           1           0
```

I know DISTINCT can select unique value but my problem is SELECTING the colum

```
SELECT user_id
     , (SELECT proj_id=17 WHERE done=1) 
  FROM project 
 WHERE theme = 1 
   AND user_id = 123 
   AND done = 1
```

if I select in a way above it will say

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

if I select multiple id's like user_id IN(123, 456,789)

I have to select hundreds of id's, so I have to SELECT in a way where WHERE clause is

```
WHERE user_id IN(123,456,789, etc)
```

Comment: You mention mysqli, which is a PHP construction. I'd handle display issues there.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get the results properly, here is the sql

```
SELECT user_id,
MAX((CASE WHEN proj_id = 17 AND done = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS proj_17,
... until 23 etc
FROM project
WHERE theme = 1
AND user_id
IN(123, 456, 789,...)
GROUP BY user_id
```

and I get result something like

```
uid | proj_17 | proj_18 | ... etc
123      1         0
345      1         1
678      0         1
```

which what I wanted